# Why is this Python class copying another class contents?

Tags: python, class, variables

I'm trying to understand an estrange behavior in Python.

I have the next python code:

```
class IntContainer:

    listOfInts = []

    def __init__(self, initListOfInts):

        for i in initListOfInts:
            self.listOfInts.append(i)

    def printInts(self):

        print self.listOfInts

if __name__ == "__main__":

    intsGroup1 = [1,2,3,4]
    intsGroup2 = [4,5,6,7]

    intsGroups = [intsGroup1,intsGroup2]

    intsContainers = []

    for ig in intsGroups:
        newIntContainer = IntContainer(ig)
        intsContainers.append(newIntContainer)

    for ic in intsContainers:
        print ic.listOfInts
```

I expect to get something like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
```

But i get:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

I have check the next question:

[why is python reusing a class instance inside in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876905/why-is-python-reusing-a-class-instance-inside-in-function)

And a lot of Python reference, but I can not understand what is happening. I think is related with the `newIntContainer` identifier reutilization, but I do not understand it deeply.

Why Python appears to reused the last reference for the new object, even if I have added it to a permanent list? What can I do to resolve this behavior?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you made `listOfInts` a *class* variable, that's what `self.listOfInts` is accessing, whatever `self` instance it may be; so, all the `append`s are going to the **same** list.

If that's not what you want, you need to make `listOfInts` an *instance* variable, for example by assigning `self.listOfInts = []` at the start of the `__init__` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot...

I came from C++, PHP and others where you do not have something like class-shared variables (class variable)... I just thought I was defining a regular object parameter (instance variable)...

Comment: Actually, both C++ and PHP have class (static) fields.

Answer (score 2):

listOfInts has been defined as a class variable.

Class variables are shared by all the instances of the class.

This behavior is useful if you want to save class-related state (a typical example would be when you want to know the number of instances of the class created.

If you want listOfInts to be unique for each instance, then you should define it in **init** or other method of the class as self.listOfInts